# D2L Brightspace SSO authentication in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, desire2learn, valence

I have been able to POST a soap request using the Boomerang client to return an expiring GUID (for SSO).

I am now trying to implement the same in C# ASP.NET. I have been given a working classic ASP example which works as expected:

```
<%


Option Explicit

Dim objHttp
Dim xmlData
Dim GUIDUrl
Dim SSOUrl
Dim redirectURL
Dim guidType
Dim orgId
Dim installCode
Dim TTL
Dim key
Dim user

' ====================================
' CONFIGURE THIS SECTION
' ====================================
  GUIDUrl = "https://{URL}/d2l/guids/D2L.Guid.2.asmx"
  SSOUrl  = "https://{URL}/d2l/lp/auth/login/ssoLogin.d2l"
  guidType = "SSO"
  orgId = "12947"
  installCode = "{Please Set this Value}"
  TTL = "30"
  key = "{Please Set this Value}"
  user = "{Replace with an existing username or OegDefinedId}"
' ====================================
' END OF CONFIGURATION
' ====================================

  Dim strResult, getusername

    strResult = GUIDUrl & "/GenerateExpiringGuid" '?guidType=" & guidType & "&orgId=" & orgId & "&installCode=" & installCode & "&TTL=" & TTL & "&data=" & user & "&key=" & key


Set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 
  objHTTP.open "POST", strResult,false
  objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

objHttp.Send "guidType=" & guidType & "&orgId=" & orgId & "&installCode=" & installCode & "&TTL=" & TTL & "&data=" & user & "&key=" & key
  strResult=objHTTP.responseText



If objHttp.Status = 200 Then 
    Set xmlData = objHttp.ResponseXML
    RedirectURL = SSOUrl & "?username=" & user & "&guid=" & xmlData.childNodes(1).text
    Response.Redirect (RedirectURL)
End If 
Set objHttp = Nothing 


%>
```

Both the Boomerang client and the Classic ASP sample code return a 385 character string the 'GenerateExpiringGuidResult'. In both cases, I am able to include this GUID in the SSO URL querystring, along with a userID, and I am able to then successfully authenticate into the D2L Brightspace instance.

I have tried to write the equivalent in C#/ASP.NET, however my example is returning a 429 character string.

```
string guidType = "SSO";
string orgId = "1234";
string installCode = "{Please Set this Value}";
string TTL = "30";
string key = "{Please Set this Value}";
string user = "{Replace with an existing username or OegDefinedId}";

var GUIDUrl = "https://{URL}/d2l/guids/D2L.Guid.2.asmx";

var AuthURL = "https://{URL}/d2l/lp/auth/login/ssoLogin.d2l";

string postData = "guidType=" + guidType + "&orgId=" + orgId + "&installCode=" + installCode + "&TTL=" + TTL + "&data=" + user + "&key=" + key;
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(GUIDUrl + "/GenerateExpiringGuid") as HttpWebRequest;

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter.Write(postData);
requestWriter.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
string strGUID = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild.InnerText;

string strRedirect = AuthURL + "?guid=" + strGUID + "&userid=" + user;

lblResult.Text = strRedirect;
```

Trying to use this GUID (as per above), results in a 'Not Authorised' page: 'Error: Not authorised. You are not authorised to view the page you are trying to reach'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 200 response from the GUIDUrl web service, then I'd look at the encoding of the response.

[set response encoding from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044842/set-response-encoding-from-xml)

Also ensure you're looking at the correct XML node in the response.

xmlData.childNodes(1).text   vs.  xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild.InnerText

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@derekadk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249450/derekadk). Wrote this code which solves the problem:

```
    string user = "{Replace with an existing userid}";

    var GUIDUrl = "https://{URL}/d2l/guids/D2L.Guid.2.asmx";
    var AuthURL = "https://{URL}/d2l/lp/auth/login/ssoLogin.d2l";

    // Load XML file (a SOAP 1.2 request as per asmx example provided), containing key/pair values
    string filepath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/d2l_send.xml");
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(filepath);

    // Encode XML and post request
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GUIDUrl);
    byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmldoc.InnerXml);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    // Get response from server
    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default);
    string backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();

    // Load response into XML document class instance
    XmlDocument xmlResult = new XmlDocument();
    xmlResult.LoadXml(backstr);
    XmlElement root = xmlResult.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList GUIDNode = root.GetElementsByTagName("GenerateExpiringGuidResult");

    // Get GUID
    string innerObject = Server.HtmlEncode(GUIDNode[0].InnerXml);
    string strRedirect = AuthURL + "?guid=" + innerObject + "&userid=" + user;

    //lblResult.Text = "<a href='" + strRedirect + "'>Click here</a>"; 

    sr.Close();
    res.Close();

    Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
```